# Como pegar os valores dos id ao click do botão (html) no TChromium CEF4Delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium

Tenho um formulário html e este abre dentro de um form do delphi com o `TChromium`.

Como posso pegar os valores dos campos que o usuário digitou?

```
<div class="col-2 md-4 mb-3 offset-md-0 col-md-4">
    <label for="validationCustom8">Nº:</label>
    <input type="text" name="edNome" class="form-control"  placeholder="numero" required>
</div>
  <div class="col-2 md-4 mb-3 offset-md-0 col-md-4">
    <label for="validationCustom9">Tag:</label>
    <input type="text" name="edDet" class="form-control"   placeholder="Tag">
    </div>

      <div class="col-2 md-4 mb-3 offset-md-0 col-md-4">
          <label for="validationCustom7"> Nome:</label>
          <input type="text" name="edEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="nome" >             
    </div>

   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="botao" type="submit" >Salvar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma função em js que possa ser acionada por um click em um botão ou qualquer outro meio.

No Delphi você precisa registrar uma extensão no Navegador.
Ex.

```
type
  TCustomRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
  protected
    procedure OnWebKitInitialized; override;
  end;

  TExtensao = class
    class procedure click(const data: string);
  end;
```

Para a classe `TExtensao` observe que temos um procedimento chamado `click`, este será o contato com a função js, estamos criando nada mais nada menos que um listener entre o Delphi e o Navegador.

Procedimento `click`:

```
class procedure TExtensao.click(const data: string);
var
  vMensagem : ICefProcessMessage;
begin
  // Registra o Evento Click para a Extensão que criamos anteriormente
  vMensagem := TCefProcessMessageRef.New('click');
  vMensagem.ArgumentList.SetString(0, data);
  TCefv8ContextRef.Current.Browser.SendProcessMessage(PID_BROWSER, vMensagem);
end;
```

Agora, precisamos informar para o sistema que na inicialização ele capture os eventos do Navegador, então, na seção de inicialização adicione:

```
initialization 
...     
  // Inicializa virtualmente os Procedimentos externos do Navegador que no caso vai registrar o TExtension}
  CefRenderProcessHandler  := TCustomRenderProcessHandler.Create;
  CefBrowserProcessHandler := TCefBrowserProcessHandlerOwn.Create;
```

O componente `TChromium` possui um evento chamado `ProcessMessageReceived`, aqui toda vez que o listener `click` for acionado no Navegador informara ao `TCustomRenderProcessHandler` que registramos anteriormente que chegou uma nova mensagem.

Você poderá filtrar os eventos através do parâmetro `message`. algo como:

```
if message.Name = 'click' then
  message.ArgumentList.GetString(0)
```

Como o próprio nome diz `message.ArgumentList` é uma lista de argumentos enviadas pelo Navegador, e na posição 0 contem o resultado da função js que foi criada para pegar os valores dos campos desejados.

**Edit.**

Faltou a implementação do Registro do app:

```
{ TCustomRenderProcessHandler }
procedure TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnWebKitInitialized;
begin
  // Registra uma Extensão chamada "app" para o evento "click"
  TCefRTTIExtension.Register('app', TExtensao);
end;
```