# Captura de valores de um input no Delphi (TChromium)

Tags: delphi, chromium

Bom dia,

Estou utilizando HTML, CSS e JavaScript para montar um layout de um chat para um sistema de troca de mensagens que estou desenvolvendo. Até ai, tudo ok, só que devido a um problema de limitação que encontrei no TWebBrowser, migrei para o TChromium, o mesmo me possibilitou mais facilidade em diversos aspectos, porém, estou com dúvida de como posso estar pegando os valores de um input no meu código HTML. Com o TWebBrowser eu utilizava o seguinte código `arqID := Browser.OleObject.Document.All.Tags('input').item('arqID').value;`

Alguém ai sabe qual a função equivalente a que eu utilizava no TWebBrowser (OleObject) no TChromium?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**@EDIT:**
Desisti de tentar utilizar esse método para pegar os valores, consegui fazer oq eu queria utilizando a manipulação de URL no navegador, e através de um evento do Chromium que nota a mudança da URL (AddressChange), eu puxo a URL atual (`Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.Url;`) e com o POS filtro os valores que quero pegar.

Comment: Já respondi algo parecido, porém, não houve iteração com o autor da pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373648/como-pegar-os-valores-dos-id-ao-click-do-bot%c3%a3o-html-no-tchromium-cef4delphi

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função em js que possa ser acionada por um click em um botão ou qualquer outro meio.

No Delphi você precisa registrar uma extensão no Navegador.
Ex.

```
type
  TCustomRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
  protected
    procedure OnWebKitInitialized; override;
  end;

  TExtensao = class
    class procedure click(const data: string);
  end;
```

Para a classe `TExtensao` observe que temos um procedimento chamado `click`, este será o contato com a função js, estamos criando nada mais nada menos que um listener entre o Delphi e o Navegador.

Procedimento `click`:

```
class procedure TExtensao.click(const data: string);
var
  vMensagem : ICefProcessMessage;
begin
  // Registra o Evento Click para a Extensão que criamos anteriormente
  vMensagem := TCefProcessMessageRef.New('click');
  vMensagem.ArgumentList.SetString(0, data);
  TCefv8ContextRef.Current.Browser.SendProcessMessage(PID_BROWSER, vMensagem);
end;
```

Agora, precisamos informar para o sistema que na inicialização ele capture os eventos do Navegador, então, na seção de inicialização adicione:

```
initialization 
...     
  // Inicializa virtualmente os Procedimentos externos do Navegador que no caso vai registrar o TExtension}
  CefRenderProcessHandler  := TCustomRenderProcessHandler.Create;
  CefBrowserProcessHandler := TCefBrowserProcessHandlerOwn.Create;
```

O componente `TChromium` possui um evento chamado `ProcessMessageReceived`, aqui toda vez que o listener `click` for acionado no Navegador informara ao `TCustomRenderProcessHandler` que registramos anteriormente que chegou uma nova mensagem.

Você poderá filtrar os eventos através do parâmetro `message`. algo como:

```
if message.Name = 'click' then
  message.ArgumentList.GetString(0)
```

Como o próprio nome diz `message.ArgumentList` é uma lista de argumentos enviadas pelo Navegador, e na posição 0 contem o resultado da função js que foi criada para pegar os valores dos campos desejados.

**Edit.**

Faltou a implementação do Registro do app:

```
{ TCustomRenderProcessHandler }
procedure TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnWebKitInitialized;
begin
  // Registra uma Extensão chamada "app" para o evento "click"
  TCefRTTIExtension.Register('app', TExtensao);
end;
```

Comment: Parti pra sugestão que você me forneceu, porém, acredito que esteja fazendo errado. No seguinte código

```if message.Name = 'click' then
  message.ArgumentList.GetString(0)```

ao invés de trazer o valor, especifiquei um ShowMessage, para ver se a mesma estava sendo chamada, porém, nada acontece.
Criei a simples função js no html: ```<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetArqID(ID) {
      alert('ALERT: TESTE')
      return ID;
     }
    </script>```

dando essa call ```<input type="button" name="arqID" value="Teste" onclick="GetArqID(30);">```

Comment: esse alert dentro da js foi pra verificar se a função estava sendo chamada, até ai, tudo bem, o problema mesmo está na hora de executar as funções dentro do Delphi

Comment: agora basta de dentro do delphi executar a ação que deseja. Algo como: `Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('id_do_botao.click();', 'about:blank', 0);`

Comment: eu fiz o seguinte, na minha própria classe onde possuo o componente TChromium, eu implementei o código que você me passou, criei a função que especifiquei ali em cima, rodei o debug, e na hora que clico no botão onde faz a chamada do JS, nada acontece no Delphi, é como se o evento ProcessMessageReceived não estivesse sendo chamada

Comment: você não clica no HTML, você executa o click pelo Delphi... através da função do TChromium `ExecuteJavaScript`

Comment: ah, mas executar uma ação no HTML a partir do Delphi eu sei, a questão é que tipo, estou criando um sistema de chat no qual utilizo o TChromium com um HTML que criei para ser o chat, quando envio um arquivo, eu renderizo a primary key do arquivo especificado dentro do HTML junto ao seu nome, passando as tags <a></a>, quero que ao clicar no nome do arquivo, que está renderizado dentro do TChromium, execute uma ação no Delphi no qual eu consigo puxar um valor (primary key do arquivo) para que o Delphi realize o download do mesmo, vou postar umas prints no meu post acima

Comment: postei a print, dai é o seguinte, ao clicar no nome ali Chat.PNG, o Delphi detectar de alguma maneira o click nele e eu puxar o valor de algum determinado local, antes eu fiz o seguinte, através das tags </a>, eu alterei a URL passando o ID, e através da propriedade chrChat.Browser.MainFrame.Url, eu estava conseguindo trazer o valor no evento de OnAddressChange, o problema é que a página tá mudando kkk, dai já era o chat, no TWebBrowser, eu utiliza somente <a href= "#"> pra nao alterar a pagina, alterava uma input invisivel e pegava com o OleOject o valor da input